# AVC denied when trying to debug flutter app

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I've asked around and done some research on it but can't seem to find a fix

> I/example.localme( 3862): type=1400 audit(0.0:2646): avc: denied {
>   write } for name="cache" dev="sdb3" ino=82035
>   scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768
>   tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
>   I/example.localme( 3862): type=1400 audit(0.0:2647): avc: denied {
>   add_name } for name="localmeGMGRPB"
>   scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768
>   tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
>   I/example.localme( 3862): type=1400 audit(0.0:2648): avc: denied {
>   create } for name="localmeGMGRPB"
>   scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768
>   tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir
>   permissive=1

Comment: were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and it turned out to be a network / connection issue with the simulator.

**Possible solutions:**

- Turn on WiFi connection
- Factory reset the simulator (This solved my issue)
- Add internet permission if you are targeting older android versions:
  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`